# (c#) Se puede hacer que ''if'' detecte múltiples respuestas correctas de un string?

Tags: c#, string, condiciones

Soy bastante nuevo programando en c# (y en general)  y quería saber si se puede (y como) hacer que un 'if' tenga múltiples respuestas correctas de un string. por ejemplo que pudiera detectar varias ''versiones'' de la palabra ''sí'' (sí, si, si ,si) solo he logrado que puedo hacer que detecte una de ellas.

```
string respuesta = Console.readline();

if (respuesta == "si")   `
            {

                //hace cosas
            }
            else
            {

                //hace otras cosas

            }
```

Comment: Puedes usar el [operador lógico **or**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mejor, usar el operador de [comparador de strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Compare_System_String_System_String_System_StringComparison_) que viene por defecto, y pasarle un [flag](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison?view=netcore-3.1) que indique que no haga caso a acentos y mayusculas.

Usalo de la siguiente forma:

```
if (String.Compare(respuesta,"si",InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Te sugiero que por ejemplo conviertas a mayúscula (o minúscula como prefieras) el texto recibido; a este, le apliques `Replace` de tal forma de las ***i*** con acentos u utros los vuelvas solo **i**; ejemplo; luego de tu primer linea de código:

```
// Cualquiera que no sea solo "I" que la pase a "I".
respuesta= respuesta.ToUpper().Replace('Í', 'I').Replace('Ï', 'I');
```

entonces ya solo evaluarias:

```
if (respuesta=="SI") {
} else {
}
```

otra opción es que solo evalues sobre la primer letra que solo sea "S"; por consiguiente sería:

```
respuesta= respuesta.ToUpper().Substring(0, 1);

if (respuesta=="S") {
} else {
}
```

Comment: Gracias, me funciono

Comment: @Thornless si la respuesta te sirvio, recuerda aceptarla!! esa es la forma de decir gracias